# Serving static files (images and styling) in Dash app with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am creating a Dash app with Gunicorn and Nginx. In order to make the Dash app work, I needed to use the Flask server.
Now everything works (when I run docker-compose), however the static files / assets are not shown as normally with a Dash app with:

```
html.Img(src=dash_app.get_asset_url("Logo.png"))
```

```
.
├── app
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── rwg_app 
│   │       ├── assets (with Logo.png and style.css)
│   │   ├── dash_app.py 
│   │   ├── flask_app.py 
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── setup.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── run.py
├── nginx
│   ├── conf
│   └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
```

My `dash_app.py` looks as follows:

```
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from rwg_app.utils.utils_example import hello_world
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


def register_dash_app(flask_app):

    dash_app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                    server=flask_app,
                    name='Dashboard',
                    url_base_pathname="/rwg/")

    dash_app.layout = html.Div([
        html.H1('Hi RWG'),
        html.H4(hello_world()),
        html.Img(
            src=dash_app.get_asset_url("Logo.png")
        ),
        ]
    )

    return dash_app
```

```
flask_app.py
```

Looks as follows:

```
import flask
from rwg_app.dash_app import register_dash_app
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

register_dash_app(app)

@app.route("/dashboard")
def render_dashboard():
    return flask.redirect('/rwg/')
```

Finally the Dash app with the Flask server is run in `run.py` :

```
from rwg_app.flask_app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8050, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Now, my image (Logo.png) and styling is not shown as normally with Dash. I tested it without the Flask server, and then it works.

Does someone know how to use static files with Dash + Flask?

Comment: Based on [this page](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-enterprise/static-assets) your `assets` directory should be at the same level as your `dash_app.py` file. What happens if you do that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried that as well, but does not work. I guess integrating Dash with Flask screw things up

Comment: Dash itself is a Flask app. Perhaps you can forego making another one, and use the Dash app itself to handle everything?

Comment: I solved it with your hint! I had to place the assets folder at the same leven als run.py where eventually the Flask app is ran.